# What would fix a link within a div that is currently used as a clickable div

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

Hello I have a site I am working on an for this site I am making three panels flip when they are clicked on, you can think of it as a flip card concept. I have everything working but I realized that since the div itself is wrapped in an anchor tag and has a display of "block". What I have is the content inside that are links to external pages but since the div is clickable it only reads that anchor. I tried using the z-index but that doesn't seem to help as all.

This is my markup:
  
    
    
       What is ElectedFace?

```
<div class="flip_content"  id="flip1">
 <div class="content-info">
  <h5 style="text-align:center; font-size:20px; margin:3px 0 0 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span class="blue">Elected</span><span class="red">face</span></h5>
  <p>electedface is America's free social network delivering more real time news, faster   than any other website.</p>
  <p>electedface connects subscribers to their elected officials with active electedface accounts</p>

<p>electedface empowers subscribers to share their voice and turn social networking into constructive civil action.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="flip_switch" data-content_container="#flip2" data-flip_container="#flip_box2">
<div class="flipbox" id="flip_box2">
   <h4>Getting Started</h4>
</div>
</a>

 <div class="flip_content" id="flip2">
 <div class="content-info">
  <p> There are three ways to connect:</p>
     <p><a href="http://google.com">Read top news stories</a> and <a href="http://google.com">Read local news stories</a></p>
     <p><a href="http://google.com">Connect to your elected officials and start a group in your community</a></p>
     <p><a href="http://google.com">Register for free membership</a></p>
     </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="flip_switch" data-content_container="#flip3" data-flip_container="#flip_box3">
<div class="flipbox" id="flip_box3">
   <h4>Next Steps</h4>
</div>
</a>
 <div class="flip_content" id="flip3">
 <div class="content-info">
  <p>Elected officials: activate your electedface account, connect to your electorate, and enlist supporters.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Heres my Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
           $('.flip_switch').bind("click",function(){
              var element = $(this);
              var content = element.data("content_container");
              var flip_container = element.data("flip_container");
              var active_flipbox = $('.activeFlip');

              if(element.hasClass('activeFlip')){
                  //If the flipbox is already flipped
                  flip_container.revertFlip();  
              }
              else{
                  if(active_flipbox){
                    //Revert active flipbox
                    active_flipbox.revertFlip();
                    //Remove active status
                    active_flipbox.removeClass('activeFlip');
                  }
                  $(flip_container).flip({
                    direction: 'rl',
                    color: '#c8cbce',
                    content: $(content).html(),
                    speed:100,
                    onBefore: function(){
                      $(flip_container).addClass('activeFlip'); 
                    }  
                  });
              }

               return false;  
           });      
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: event.stopPropagation() can prevent the default behavior (browsing to the href of `<a>` tag) to happen. But how about using another tag like `<span>` instead of `<a>`?

Comment: Tired adding a new click function to the javascript that would look for a span tag with the class of link and data tag of location and on click it would pull the link from the data tag and goto it, but still no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me your problem is so called `bubbling`

What you need is (most likely :) :
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I tried in on the main div anchor and tried targeting the anchor links within the div.

Comment: I finally figured out how to use this function, thank you. I had to make the div clickable rather than using another anchor tag.